# ie7 float table row left isn't working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am working on a table that I cannot edit, I cannot add any HTML, I cannot add any JS. Everything has been pre-generated and all I can do is add CSS to it.

So table has 2 rows, one is sidebar, second is center content. I wanted to make the sidebar 210px wide and float it left, the same I did to center content. All works fine in all browsers but IE7. When I inspect it with IE7 developer tools, I can see that the row and the TD under it are always 100% wide and there is no way to assign a width value to it.

Is there a work around to this problem?

Sample code.

```
<table>
<tr id="sidebar"><td>Some data</td></tr>
<tr id="main"><td>Some data 2</td></tr>
</table>

CSS:
#sidebar
{
display:block;
width:210px;
float:left;
}
#main
{
display:block;
width:730px;
float:left;
}
```

Please advise

Comment: Try `display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;`.

Comment: I didn't understood the question, do you want to assign width or you want the second td besides 1st td?

Comment: I want one tr to be next to the other one. For some reason, they are 100% wide instead of what I tell it to be.

Comment: @bobek I have the exact same issue - can't edit the markup but need to float the second tr to the right of the first tr - but having trouble with this in ie7. Did you find a solution bobek?

Comment: No, I haven't - I am sorry, and I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have ie7, but setting the rows display:table-cell; and putting a width on the table works in chrome in this example. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7Wuku/

Comment: Cell displays 1 below the other in IE7

Comment: meh. have you set proper width taking account for margin or padding?

Comment: @albert, you can use any display you want, but if you later use `float: left` or right - the computed style for such an element will be `display: block` - Try inspecting a floated element and you'll see that the `display: whatever_you_may_put_here` property is never applied

Comment: yea, the her needs like this twor rows besides each other and your renders 1 below the other if you want  use developer mode in your IE and render it as version 7 and see

Comment: you can do it in ie8 using absolute positioning and and ugly text-align; again, i don't have ie7 so i'm not 100% this will work, but try it and let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wuku/3/

Answer (score -2):

I think a good way of doing it is without the second row... Of course if you can make your markup like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="sidebar">Sidebar content</td>
        <td class="main_cont">Main content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this markup you won't need to float the `td`s, simply state the width.
A live example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/QySz2/1/

But if you can't change the markup - I'm afraid you'll never teach IE7 to float table rows))